# ¿Como crear una funcion para ingresar datos a un arreglo de estructuras?

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos

Alguien me puede explicar como hacer una funcion dentro de una estructura que pueda ingresar los datos de un arreglo de estructuras, en el visual me pedia usar punteros pero no entido como usar punteros para un arreglo de estructuras D:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Producto {
    char Nombre_Producto[50];
    float Precio;
    int Cantidad;
    void IngresarDatos();
}Productos[2];

void Producto::IngresarDatos() {
    cout << "Ingrese el Nombre";
    cin.getline(Nombre_Producto, 50, '\n');
    cout << "Ingrese la Precio: ";
    cin >> Precio;
    cout << "Ingrese la cantidad: ";
    cin >> Cantidad;
}

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        Productos[i].IngresarDatos;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El motivo por el cual no funciona el código es debido a que te faltan los paréntesis de la función:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    Productos[i].IngresarDatos();
}
```

Sin embargo, si te parece te planteo una alternativa que organice los elementos:

Por una parte declarar la estructura.

```
struct Producto {
    char Nombre_Producto[50];
    float Precio;
    int Cantidad;
};
```

Por otra, declarar la función que nos permite construir el producto (independiente de la struct).

```
Producto construirProducto() {
    struct Producto producto;

    cout << "Ingrese el Nombre\n";
    cin.getline(producto.Nombre_Producto, 50, '\n');
    cout << "Ingrese la Precio: \n";
    cin >> producto.Precio;
    cout << "\nIngrese la cantidad: ";
    cin >> producto.Cantidad;

    return producto;
}
```

Y, finalmente en el main, crear un array del tamaño que deseas, que almacena structs de Producto. En el bucle de iteraciones generas cada vez un nuevo producto que es añadido a la lista.

```
int main() {
    int cantidadProductos = 2;

    Producto productos[cantidadProductos];
    for (int i = 0; i < cantidadProductos; i++) {
        productos[i] = construirProducto();
    }

    return 0;
}
```